# How to overcome the fault in apostrophe strings.xml in android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error in strings.xml file in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657047/error-in-strings-xml-file-in-android)

I used three or more lines in strings.xml.

For eg:

```
<string name="menu_settings">Google's Android</string>
```

It contains apostrophe.But it shows error.When I remove that,it gets clear.Whether it doesn't support apostrophe in android?  How to overcome  that?Is there any solution?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to escape it. Replace it with &apos;

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response.

Comment: @Thrakbad:Easy one..:) thanks to u too..

Comment: Escape the character. Something like Google\'s Android