# Android Studio Error Access Denied?

Tags: android, android-studio

I worked on my project last night and everything went great. Test the app on an emulator and even open and closed the Android Studio IDE several times that day with no issues. Today however it wont build and gives me an error.

Error:
[image]

The error is the / in the drivers license of the string "dl".
[image]

Now I have run into this error before and all I did to fix it was change the / into \ and it fixed it. This time after I rebuild it, it changes what I fixed back to the / and throws up the error. Before I restarted my computer I got this error in addition to the ones you see now.

C:\Users\Austin\AndroidStudioProjects\Intelwatch\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\recyclerview-v7\23.1.1\jars\classes.jar' to 'C:\Users\Austin.AndroidStudio1.5\system\jars'. Reason: Access is denied.

I tried changing the rights to my username and I also ran the program under as admin but nothing worked. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to use back slash (\), not (/)

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5657189/5333674

Comment: I know lol. After I fix it, the system returns it back to being incorrect. As if its not saving my correction and re pulling the same unchanged file from last night.

Comment: You are trying to edit an auto-generated file. It is dumb that the error points you to that file instead of the source, but the correct place to edit any XML resource is in the `res/` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell by the path of the file, this is the incorrect values.xml file. I have had this same exact error as well. Here is how to fix it:

1: Go to the drop down menu and select Android instead of Project or anything else. [image: Dropdown menu]

2: Navigate to the actual strings.xml or values.xml file here.[image: The strings.xml file in the correct location.]

3: Change your desired string. In this case, your string would look like or similar to this:
[image: Edited string]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me before.
Editing that(the code on screen) will not help.
You will manually have to go to the `strings.xml` and change it there.
If you see carefully, when you run the program the code is reverted back.
Hence you have to manually change it from `strings.xml`
Hope this helps