# Android Studio Build Error Not Going Away

Tags: android-studio, error-handling

I am using Android Studio v2.1.2.. 
This is my attempt at android development so, I am making a lot of mistakes..
However when i am correcting them, and trying to build again it's still showing the same errors;
I tried to clean the project, tried restarting Android Studio but of no luck..
Like in this pic, this apostrophe error is not going away.. i had similar errors earlier also..
They were not severe so i kept them that way..
I know this is a stupid question, but anyone could tell me how to solve this I would be grateful.
Thanks in Advance...[My Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6RnO.jpg)

Comment: update your value.xml

Comment: @AmitBasliyal I have edited the code in value.xml but it's still showing the error; if i delete all occurrences of the error, it still re-generates the error by bringing back the string text.

Comment: try other `apptheme` and update your  value.xml file here may help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in strings.xml file in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657047/error-in-strings-xml-file-in-android)

Comment: No. Mine is different .. Read the question..

Comment: I tried other apptheme too;@AmitBasliyal

Answer (score 0):

You have this: "`Let's take a test!!!`" in your `values.xml` file.

Update it to this: "`Let\'s take a test!!!`".

---

Always put a `\` before a `'`*(Apostrophe)* in your strings.xml/values.xml/etc.

---

I hope I helped.

Comment: I did that. But errors are not going away.. The gradle re-instates the error while building...

Comment: @Nirmala Did you try cleaning your project? Show me your values.xml, otherwise I can't help you.