# How to type apostrophe character in android strings xml

Tags: android, xml

If i try to do things like this, it doesn't work... (empty string or no resource type error)

```
<string name="make_sales_order">FAIRE L'ORDRE DE VENTE </string>
```

how to use apostrophe character in android string xml.any ideas?

Comment: Please describe what exactly doesn't work and why do you expect it to work

Comment: Is this a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657047/error-in-strings-xml-file-in-android ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**1. For Single Quote (')**

You can use `\'` in your string resources.

**or**

You can enclose the string in double quotes. For example:

`"This'll work"` will simply become `This'll work` once parsed

**2. For double quote (")**

```
"message \"quote string 1\" and \"quote string 2\" end message"
```

**3. To represent in views xml (eg layout.xml), you have to use HTML character entities (like ")**

```
"message &quot;quoted string 1&quot; and &quot;quoted string 2&quot; end message"
```

Though Android Studio in particular will complain about hardcoded strings and tell you to use a string resource in layout files instead of course!

Answer (score 8):

Use \' in your string.xml

```
<string name="make_sales_order">FAIRE L\'ORDRE DE VENTE </string>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<string name="make_sales_order">FAIRE L\&#39;ORDRE DE VENTE</string>`

Answer (score 1):

The curved apostrophe is a little more professional for user-facing messaging than the straight one mentioned above. The unicode for start and end curved apostrophes is `2018` and `2019`. In Android **strings.xml**, you preface with a `\u`, `u\2019`

For example: The possessive word Bob's would be: `<string>Bob\u2019s</string>`

Here is a reference for punctuation UTF codes: https://symbl.cc/en/unicode/blocks/general-punctuation/